# How to measure number of asserts per line of code in SonarQube

Tags: junit, sonarqube, assert

We are attempting to get another view of our code coverage over the standad line and branch-coverage. We would like to get the number of asserts per line/method/class in order to see if we just are running though the code or if we are getting expected results.

So, how to measure the number of asserts in a codebase in sonarcube?

Comment: "to see if we just are running though the code or if we are getting expected results" you are looking for mutation testing here rather than anything else. Checkout what http://pitest.org/ does (there is even a SonarQube plugin for  it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a product called pitest that answers to the goal of my question. And there is a plugin for sonar and pitest. So the answer to somehow verify if we actually checks for anything in the tests is: pitest.